# Why is there an introductory paragraph in a book translated into German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, book

I am reading a German translation of the American novel "The Pastures of Heaven" by John Steinbeck, and I noticed that on the first page there is a short summary paragraph that does not exist in the original version.

For reference, the paragraph reads:

> Dies ist die Geschichte eines Tales, dessen Anblick für viele Menschen eine große Verheißung war. Manche träumte davon, einmal an diesen Ort zurückzukehren, dessen Schönheit sie einst geschaut hatten, um für immer dort zu bleiben.

I own several editions of the original version (in English) and none of them contain this first paragraph. Was this added for a particular reason, or is this a common practice for German translations?

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to help with the editorial history of a book. Of course it's not common practice to add cheesy introductions to German book translations. Looks like an editorial decision for whatever reason. Maybe it's blurb that for some reason ended up as an introduction, maybe the translator thought that they needed to add an allusion to "heaven" since "Himmel" isn't as specific.

Comment: Just out of interest: Is the paragraph recognizably set apart from the main text (through font, spacing...) in your book?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the German language per se.

Comment: I believe the question is on-topic here. At the same time I don't see how one can answer it beyond what HalvarF wrote in their comment.

Comment: It might help to know the bibliographic data (year of publication, publisher and translator) of the translated book.

Comment: For now, I can only tell, that I have seen this in German books before. Off the top of my head, I only remember books from Erich Kästner. If I remember correctly, he does not just do this in his books for children, but also in _Fabian_. That might be a starting point for a research.

Comment: Some translated books have an added "Translator's preface" and this seems to be an example, though perhaps it's a bit short to be called a "preface". I'm thinking Steinbeck isn't the same household name to German speakers as it is to Americans, so perhaps the translator thought a blurb like this would be useful for the audience. I agree that, since the questions isn't actually about the German language, it's technically off-topic for the site.

Comment: The sentence seems indeed to be set as the first paragraph of the book as translated by Hans Ulrich Straub in 1954, not as some sort of preface. [In this forum thread](https://www.buechereule.de/wbb/thread/82627-die-ersten-drei-saetze-eures-aktuellen-buches/?postID=2779113#post2779113), users were invited to post the first three sentences of the book they are currently reading. [Google Books](https://www.google.de/search?q=Dies+ist+die+Geschichte+eines+Tales%2C+dessen+Anblick+f%C3%BCr+viele+Menschen+eine+gro%C3%9Fe+Verhei%C3%9Fung+war.&tbm=bks) seems to find it in a Reader's digest from 1960.

Comment: Also the French translation does not contain it. https://www.amazon.fr/P%C3%A2turages-du-ciel-John-Steinbeck/dp/2070366928/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3MD0CH2X26TWP&keywords=steinbeck+les+paturages+du+ciel&qid=1654596366&sprefix=steinbeck+les+p%C3%A2turages+du+ciel+%2Caps%2C137&sr=8-1&asin=B008H6IREU&revisionId=dd8fabc8&format=1&depth=1

Comment: It is certainly not a preface, it is the first paragraph of the text and German readers will believe that it is a (translated) part of Steinbeck's orginal text. It must have been added autonomously by the translator, but the reasons remain mysterious.

Comment: @marquinho No, it looks like a regular part of the text.

Comment: I reached out to the publisher and they were unable to offer any clarity. From the contact: "Leider können wir diese nicht beantworten, da wir keine Unterlagen mehr haben, um das zu rekonstruieren."

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating such paragraphs into the body text would be highly unusual. But in contrast to American publishing, it is not uncommon for German books to contain brief summaries in the front matter of the book -- often with info about the publisher.